# How to add a round disk in a ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, output

This should be very easy, but I can't make it to work properly.  I need to add a *circular* disk in the following ListPlot code:

```
dot[gamma_] := Disk[{gamma, gamma 5}, 0.25]

graph1[gamma_] := ListPlot[
    Table[{x, gamma x^2},
        {x, -4, 4, 0.5}
    ],
Frame -> True,
Ticks -> All,
GridLines -> Automatic,
GridLinesStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[0.5], Dashed],
PlotRange -> All,
PlotStyle -> Thick,
Joined -> True,
Mesh -> None,
InterpolationOrder -> 4,
Epilog -> {Red, dot[gamma]}  (* This disk should stay circular, not oval! *)
]

graph1[-1]
```

Currently, the red disk is a deformed oval.  I need it to stay circular, whatever the AspectRatio of the plot.  What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Add `AspectRatio -> Automatic`, or use `Point` instead of `Disk`.

Comment: If the image aspect ratio does not equal the coordinate aspect ratio, then circles appears as ellipses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change to use `Offset`:

```
dot[gamma_] := Disk[{gamma, gamma 5}, Offset[{4, 4}]]
```

[image]

Comment: What is the Offset in the Disk?

Comment: Please change to `{10,4}` as an example to see the effect. Also press `F1` for the doc page that has example(s).

Comment: @Cham It's the radius.  Look up `Offset` and `Scaled`, etc. It's  a question of image coordinates vs. graphics coordinates....See docs for `Plot` > Options > Epilog > 2nd example.

Comment: Is there a way to make the point size "absolute", i.e the same size on screen whatever the AspectRatio and whatever the PlotRange?

Comment: Isn't it compliant with those two requirements already?

Comment: @Cham Read the docs! The units for `Offset` are the same as those for `AbsoluteThickness`, `AbsolutePointSize`, etc.